# Can't create automatic weights

Tags: weight-painting

When in `Edit Mode` I select mesh and then armature and then press Ctrl + P -> `With Automatic Weights`, then it don't create weights. I'm getting error `Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones`. How can I solve it? Here is model https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-V8eIcem9k21v9kCZvqn6ZYUCIsewtv/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: If you scale it 3 times (and apply the scale) it will work fine (then scale down if needed), I don't know why it didn't work because it was already big and there was no big apparent problem (maybe inner faces and overlapping vertices but removing them didn't seem to fix the problem). Scaling up helps to parent correctly sometimes. Maybe someone will explain what messes up with the current size...

Comment: @moonboots weird that scaling would work, because there are interior faces, duplicate vertices and non-manifold sections in that mesh.

Comment: yes but as I said fixing all the problems you cite doesn't seem to help, only scaling up, even though the mesh is already big, so there's something I don't understand here

Comment: The topology looks ok at first glance. But there are a lot of "quads" that are actually n-gons. These faces have 5 vertices. And there are non-flat faces and also a few duplicated verts that get merged if you use the *Merge by Distance* operation. I would clean up the mesh first. You can activate the 3D Print Tool addon that comes with Blender. It has a Check button. In *Edit* mode, you can use the *Select* button to display the bad faces.